# Calling a PHP function from inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is my javascript code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".five").click(function(){
<?php echo updatepoints();?>
});
});
</script>
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php
function updatepoints() {
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die ("Cannot connect to database");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *from member WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$points = $row["points"];
$points = $points + 5;
mysql_query("UPDATE member set points='" . $points . "' WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'");
}
?>
```

Both these codes are on same page one below other. This does not seem to update the values. How should I proceed?

Comment: Will need to do AJAX at this point if you want it to live load that php on click. This instance will only load the php once when the page finishes loading. Look into AJAX jQuery

Comment: *...plus,* I take it you have `session_start();` loaded somewhere?

Comment: Try to echo update query and execute it to find any errors.

Comment: Yes, I have session_start() at the beginning.

Comment: What about the rest of your code/HTML? Or, is that "it"?

Comment: What does that mean? I did not understand that.

Comment: Well we can give you help on the jQuery and such if you submit more code...for example do you use a form or how do you arrive at the click funciton?

Comment: This `$(".five").click(function()` is supposed to be called by a button with a class called `five`. Your JS won't fire up on its own like that. Get rid of the JS and keep `<?php echo updatepoints();?>` and you'll see it will work. Then, use Ajax.

Comment: I've posted something below that you give a try. It's part of a list of scripts I use for questions like this. @Programmingcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file called ajax_update.php . Inside that file add your function and user ajax to call that function.

ajax_update.php

```
<?php
function updatepoints() {
      mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die (mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db("database") or die ("Cannot connect to database");
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT *from member WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'");
      $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
      $points = $row["points"];
      $points = $points + 5;
      mysql_query("UPDATE member set points='" . $points . "' WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'");
}
if($_POST['action_type'] == 'update') {
    updatepoints();
}
?>
```

change your script like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".five").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "ajax_update.php",
            data : {action_type:"update"},
            success : function(html){
            }
        });
     });
});
</script>
```

You can change your ajax PHP file as separate file for ajax and class. Add functions in class. Let it be neat and clear

Comment: Thank you. You answer was the easiest to understand and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Here, try this:

Sidenote: `content.php` will be your SQL file, which is being called by `xmlhttp.open("GET","content.php",true);`.

This will work, assuming your SQL is already good.

```
<!doctype html>

<head>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","content.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>

</head>

</head>
<body>
<script>
setInterval(loadXMLDoc,5000);
</script>
<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery, it makes things simpler:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("update_user_points.php", { username: 'someuser' },  function(response) {
      console.log(response);//check your console
    });
});
</script>
```

I didn't see how you start the session, but this example passes the `username` value from the client to PHP. if you just incrementing the points by 5 you can do it in a better way check this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']){

function updatepoints($username) {

    mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database") or die ("Cannot connect to database");
    $query = sprintf("UPDATE member set points = points + 5 WHERE username='%s'",
                      mysql_real_escape_string($username));
    // Perform Query
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // Check result
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }else{
        echo 'update success';
    }
}
//call the function
updatepoints($_POST['username']);
}
?>
```